# CSS difference bwteen Pseudo-classes and Pseudo-elements in specificity calculation ?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I learned how to calculate css specificity based on http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity
However, based on this reference, I don't understand what is the difference between Pseudo-classes (from c) and  Pseudo-elements (from d)?

For example,

```
input[type="text"]:hover
```

hover is Pseudo-classes (from c) or  Pseudo-elements (from d)?

compared with `input[type="text"].error`, which one has a higher specificity?

Comment: the pseudo elements are generate by browser, it's differents state of a element like `:hover`, `:checked`, `:focus` you can associate this at a user interract. the second things `.error` is a class, it could be use for general css on some differents element. We put classes after some verification (for input in a form) in JS to inform the user

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify myself a bit. At this point, I am talking about css selector , so what I am doing is writing css input[type="text"]:hover {}, and input[type="text"].error{}. Since they will have the same effect, so I want to know which one has higher specificity. If they have the same specificity, then I need to decide the order.

Comment: You mentioned the pseudo elements generated by browse, so "hover" here is not a pseudo elements, but a pseudo class, right? Can you please give me an example of pseudo element. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo classes (c) have a specificity of 10

Pseudo elements (d) has a specificity of 1

Both

`input[type="text"]:hover` and

```
input[type="text"].error
```

have a specificity of 21

`input` (element - 'd') = 1

`[type="text"]` (attribute - 'c') = 10

`:hover` (pseudo class - 'c') = 10

`.error` (class - 'c') = 10

There are also online specificity calculators available, such as [this one](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 0):

The page cited says the same as CSS specifications such as CSS3 Selectors, section [9. Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity), though in less detail and non-authoritatively. The key point is that in specificity, pseudo-class selectors are treated like class selectors and pseudo-element selectors like type selectors (tag names). This means that a pseudo-class selector is more specific than a pseudo-element selector. The idea behind this is that classes (and pseudo-classes) refer to elements in a more specific way, like “Cadillac” (a class of cars, so to say) is more specific than “car” (a type of things, so to say).

Regarding `:hover`, whar matters is how it is specified in CSS specs. It so happens that it is a pseudo-class selector. This is natural, since it refers to an element that is in a specific state, so it can be characterized as a “dynamic class”.

Thus, `input[type="text"]:hover` and `input[type="text"].error` have equal specificity.